# What structure is this and how can this be converted to JSON

Tags: c#, json, string

I am getting the following string output from a device:

> [Body{id=0, status=NOT_TRACKING, centerOfMass=Vector3D{x=0.0, y=0.0,
> z=0.0}, joints=[Joint{type=HEAD, status=NOT_TRACKED,
> depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=SHOULDER_SPINE, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_SHOULDER, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_ELBOW, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_HAND, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_SHOULDER, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_ELBOW, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_HAND, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=MID_SPINE, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=BASE_SPINE, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_HIP, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_KNEE, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_FOOT, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_HIP, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_KNEE, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_FOOT, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=LEFT_WRIST, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=RIGHT_WRIST, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, Joint{type=NECK, status=NOT_TRACKED, depthPosition=Vector2D{x=0.0, y=0.0}, worldPosition=Vector3D{x=0.0,
> y=0.0, z=0.0}, orientation=Matrix3{values=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}], handPoseInfo=HandPoseInfo{leftHand=UNKNOWN, rightHand=UNKNOWN}, areJointsEnabled=true, areHandPosesEnabled=true}]

It looks like JSON but it's not. I would like to know what format it is and how I can convert it to JSON or map it to an object using C#.

Comment: Is there any documentation associated with the device that might help. It might be a good idea to also include details of the device in case somebody recognises it.

Comment: This format could be very specific to device that is producing it. Probably need to know what device to better assist.

Comment: It appears to be custom structured data. Do a search on the output device and who makes it get a "schema" to use to process the data.